# Platform IOでライブラリのインクルード方法

Tags: vscode, esp32

現在、ESP32基板をVisual Studio Codeの追加機能のPlatrom IOでコンパイルや書き込みなどを勉強中です。

なお、ESP32にSPI通信のTFTディスプレイを接続してGUIプログラミングも行いたいため、LVGLというGUIライブラリも勉強したいと思っています。

そこで、GithubでLVGLのサンプルコードを見つけたので、ダウンロードしてみました。
https://github.com/bigw00d/esp-idf-littlevgl-sample

このサイトのmainフォルダにある[main.c](https://github.com/bigw00d/esp-idf-littlevgl-sample/blob/master/main/main.c)をPlatform IOで作成した空プロジェクトのsrcフォルダに入れてとりあえずビルドしてみました。

すると、次のようなエラーコードが出力されました。

```
src\main.c:10:23: fatal error: lvgl/lvgl.h: No such file or directory
```

Platform IOのこのプロジェクトフォルダ内のlibフォルダに、[githubのこのプロジェクトで使用されているコンポーネントファイル](https://github.com/bigw00d/esp-idf-littlevgl-sample/tree/master/components)などが置いてあったので、それをそのままコピーしてみたのですが、エラーが解消されません。

Visual Studio codeでmain.cファイルを見てみると、エラーが出ている10行目の

```
#include "lvgl/lvgl.h"
```

この行では、下線の波線が出ていて、マウスを近づけると

```
#includeエラーが発生しました。includePathを更新して下さい。この翻訳単位（D:\test\ESP32Test\src\main.c）では、破線が無効になっています。
```

ソースファイルを開けません。”lvgl/lvgl.h”

このような表示が出てきて解消されません。

このlibフォルダに入れたlvgl.hファイルを読み込めるようにすることはできますでしょうか？
どうぞ、ご教示頂きますよう、宜しくお願い致します。

（追記　VS Codeの画像を追加。）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

（9/25追記　lv_font.hファイルが見つからないエラー）
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/290596

Comment: 実際に、main.c と lvgl/lvgl.h のあるフォルダの位置関係はどうなっていますか？フルパスで記述するなり、スクリーンショットで示していただいた方が的確な回答が得られると思います。

Comment: エラーが発生している際のVS Codeの画像を追加してみました。

Comment: #include "lv_examples/lv_apps/demo/demo.h"
だと、ビルド時にエラーとなります。～の下線が出ています。

#include "lv_apps/demo/demo.h"
こちらのパスにするとエラーは出ません。

Comment: #include "lv_examples/lv_apps/demo/demo.h" このパスでもビルドが成功できるようにすることはできますでしょうか？

Comment: "include"というフォルダがあるのに、"lib"というフォルダにヘッダファイルなどを配置しているのはなぜでしょうか？質問者さんのプロジェクトの具体的な設定は判りませんが、少なくともlibがインクルードパスに設定されていなければ、相対パスで書かれたインクルードファイルは読み込めません。https://qiita.com/sage-git/items/ffe463c0de05344d721b などを参考に設定してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。パスを追加する方法がわかり助かりました。

Comment: includeフォルダに、esp-idf-littlevgl-sampleプロジェクト内のcomponentフォルダ内のヘッダーファイルを移したところ、読み込んでくれるようになったのですが、include\lvgl\src\lv_font\lv_font.h　このヘッダーファイルが見つからないとのエラーが出てきます。解決方法などありますでしょうか？